# Excel-VBA Convert string to phonetic alphabet

Tags: vba, excel

I created an Excel workbook with VBA to help with user account creation. It generates 8 character passwords and then displays the password phonetically.

**Everything is working fine, I just want to improve my code.**

This portion of the code takes the alpha characters in the password and spits out the NATO phonetic equivalent. It seems like I should be able to accommodate upper and lowercase characters with half the amount of code, I just don't know how.

```
Public Function Wordify(char As String)
 Wordify = Switch(char = "A", "ALFA", char = "B", "BRAVO", char = "C", "CHARLIE", char = "D", "DELTA", char = "E", "ECHO", char = "F", "FOXTROT", _
  char = "G", "GOLF", char = "H", "HOTEL", char = "I", "INDIA", char = "J", "JULIETT", char = "K", "KILO", char = "L", "LIMA", char = "M", "MIKE", _
  char = "N", "NOVEMBER", char = "O", "OSCAR", char = "P", "PAPA", char = "Q", "QUEBEC", char = "R", "ROMEO", char = "S", "SIERRA", char = "T", "TANGO", _
  char = "U", "UNIFORM", char = "V", "VICTOR", char = "W", "WHISKEY", char = "X", "XRAY", char = "Y", "YANKEE", char = "Z", "ZULU", _
  char = "a", "alfa", char = "b", "bravo", char = "c", "charlie", char = "d", "delta", char = "e", "echo", char = "f", "foxtrot", _
  char = "g", "golf", char = "h", "hotel", char = "i", "india", char = "j", "juliett", char = "k", "kilo", char = "l", "lima", char = "m", "mike", _
  char = "n", "november", char = "o", "oscar", char = "p", "papa", char = "q", "quebec", char = "r", "romeo", char = "s", "sierra", char = "t", "tango", _
  char = "u", "uniform", char = "v", "victor", char = "w", "whiskey", char = "x", "xray", char = "y", "yankee", char = "z", "zulu")
End Function
```

Comment: You could create an array of all the upper-case values, then based on the ASCII code of `char` return either the upper or lower cased version of the word at the correct index in that array.

Answer (score 4):

Simplfying Ian's code further:

---

```
Public Function Wordify(char As String) As String
  On Error Resume Next  
  Wordify = Split("alpha,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot,golf,hotel,india,juliett,kilo,lima,mike,november,oscar,papa,quebec,romeo,sierra,tango,uniform,victor,whiskey,xray,yankee,zulu", ",")(Asc(LCase(char)) - 97)
End Function
```

---

PS. I also replaced "alfa" with the spelling used within the NATO phonetic alphabet; "alpha".

Comment: Add `If char = UCase(char) Then Wordify = UCase(Wordify)` and it will return both cases.

Comment: Thanks (to you both).  You could also use the UPPER(...) in-cell function around the return from the Wordify(...) function.

Comment: Awesome, thank you guys!

I originally had "ALPHA" and "JULIET" but after looking at the NATO Phonetic Alphabet on wikipedia, I changed them to ALFA and JULIETT.

Comment: [ https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/txvv3j/excelvba_phonetic_alphabet_generator_detecting/ ]

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. A simplified version.

```
Public Function Wordify(char As String)
Phonetics = Split("alfa,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot,golf,hotel,india,juliett,kilo,lima,mike,november,oscar,papa,quebec,romeo,sierra,tango,uniform,victor,whiskey,xray,yankee,zulu", ",") 'storing your custom values into an array Phonetics
AsciofChar = Asc(char) 'finding the ascii of the character passed to the function
If AsciofChar >= 65 And AsciofChar <= 90 Then 'checking whether the char is upper case
    Wordify = UCase(Phonetics(AsciofChar - 65)) 'selecting the value from the array corresponding to the char passed
ElseIf AsciofChar >= 97 And AsciofChar <= 122 Then 'checking whether the char is in lower case
    Wordify = LCase(Phonetics(AsciofChar - 97)) 'selecting the value from the array corresponding to the char passed
End If
End Function
```